# The Schrodinger equation for time-dependent Hamiltonian after one timestep, taking exponential or use ode solver?

Tags: ode, computational-physics

The Schrodinger equation for time-dependent Hamiltonian is

$$i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}\psi(t) = H(t)\psi(t) \, .$$

Assuming I knew $\psi(t)$, I want to know $\psi(t+\Delta t)$.

Should I take exponential or use ode solver?

I know that the mathematical solution after one timestep should be (or not?)

$$\psi(t+\Delta t) = e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}H(t)\Delta t}\psi(t) \, .$$

It gives a different result from using ode solver unfortunately. Which is the most correct one?

Comment: When taking an exponential of a matrix, that's usually much harder than doing a single timestep of an ODE solver. Any time you solve a linear time-independent ODE, that's computing a matrix exponential using an ODE solver instead of using some other method (you seem to be freezing the $H$ during the timestep to convert your problem to this). Also, what do you mean it gives a different result? Have you ruled out bugs in your own code, and can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show the error and the details? More details about what you're trying to do would really help.

Comment: Your "mathematical solution" is not correct; you have frozen H over the whole timestep.

Comment: yes i know but that is the only way i can input numerically and take the timestep to very small

Comment: How are you going to compute the matrix/operator exponential? If you approximate it using just the first two Taylor terms, then you end up with exactly one time step of the forward Euler method.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth `expm` function in matlab is what I used. I think it should be pretty accurate in that it keeps a lot of terms.

Comment: @diff -- then it's also pretty expensive. You can do a *lot* of time steps for the equivalent of one matrix exponential!

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth do u mean `expm` is very expensive?

Comment: Yes, `expm` is indeed very expensive!

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth but it seems that doing `expm` is way faster than ode in my program. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: It all depends on the number of time steps you ask the ODE solver to do. If you ask for 1000 time steps but only an expansion of expm into 5 terms, then the latter is going to be faster but the former is going to be more accurate. And the other way around.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth is diagonalizing the matrix before expm faster?

Comment: Yes! For example, if $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, then you can write it as $A=U\Lambda U^T$, then $e^A=U e^\Lambda U^T$ where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. Taking the exponential $e^\Lambda$ is cheap.